# Draw rectangle border thickness

Tags: java, swing, awt

Is it possible to do draw a rectangle with a given border thickness in an easy way?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you are drawing on a [Graphics2D](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) object, you can use the `setStroke()` method:

```
Graphics2D g2;
double thickness = 2;
Stroke oldStroke = g2.getStroke();
g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(thickness));
g2.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
g2.setStroke(oldStroke);
```

If this is being done on a Swing component and you are being passed a `Graphics` object, you can downcast it to a `Graphics2D`.

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
```

Comment: Do I have to unset the stroke

Comment: @JPC, yes.  The stroke will then stay thicker.  I will add code that addresses that issue.  Stand by.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do this : Border with colored line with thickness 5.

```
Border linebor = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(0xAD85FF), 5);
```

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Tested code with buffered image with different thickness values**:

Graphics2D g = bufferedImage.createGraphics();

int height = //image height

int width = //image height

int borderWidth = //border thickness

int borderControl = 1;

//set border color

g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

//set border thickness

g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(borderWidth));

//to fix issue for even numbers

if(borderWidth%2 == 0){

borderControl = 0;

}

g.drawLine(0, 0, 0, height);

g.drawLine(0, 0, width, 0);

g.drawLine(0, height – borderControl, width, height – borderControl);

g.drawLine(width – borderControl, height – borderControl, width – borderControl, 0);
```